# Zusammengesetztes Substantiv mit Fall "Niederlassungs-Isolation" vs. "Niederlassung-Isolation"

Tags: genitive, compound

Das gefragte Wort ist der Name einer Einstellung, die die Isolation von Daten verschiedener Niederlassungen an- oder abzuschalten. Es werden also Niederlassungen von einander Isoliert.

1. Sollte man nun das Genitiv-S anhängen? "Wessen Daten werden Isoliert? Die der Niederlassungen?"
2. Gibt es dahingehend überhaupt eine Regel?

Comment: Ich verstehe die Frage nicht. Das (erste) s in "Niederlassungsisolation" is ein [Fugen-s](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fugenlaut) und kein Genitiv-s.

Comment: Im Sinne der Verständlichkeit könnte man auch das nehmen, was du zum Beschreiben nutzt statt es auf Krampf in ein Wort zu pressen: Daten ((der Niederlassungen) voneinander) isolieren. Mit den Klammern deute ich an, was man bei bekannten Kontext ggf weglassen kann. Oder: Isolation der Niederlassungen (voneinander)

Comment: Vielen Dank Roland. Das Fugen-S war mir nicht bekannt. Damit ist mir aber auch klar, warum ich die Variante mit S angenehmer in der Aussprache finde.

Auch vielen Dank planetmaker. Guter Einwand, ich möchte jedoch einen festen Begriff etablieren, der eine kontextunabhängige Anwendung erlaubt.

Comment: Beim Fugen-S (und anderen Fugenlauten) beachte aber, daß es (nicht in diesem Fall, aber bei anderen Wörtern) regionale Unterschiede in der Anwendung geben kann: zB "Adventkranz" (Österreich) vs. "Adventskranz" (Deutschland) oder "Schweinsbraten" vs. "Schweinebraten".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bei Wörtern mit -ung wird oft das Fugenelement "s" verwendet.
Trotz Fugen-s ist der Bindestrich weiterhin zur Klarheit möglich.
[Quelle](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/fragen/3038).

Du hast recht damit, dass das Fugen-s von der Genitivendung abstammt.
Davon hat es sich aber entfernt.

> Das Tageslicht -> Des Tages Licht